# Why is Post not Coming out

Tags: php, html, post

when i try to post something for an online shop it doesnt show the Username, but it shows the item.

HTML:

```
    <style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image: url(abstractsdark6.jpg);
}
body,td,th {
    color: #FFF;
}
</style>


<center>



<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><img src="tengokucraftshop.png" width="1002" height="215">
<p><span style="font-family:'Myriad Web Pro'; font-size:12pt">Thank you for Buying a 1 Time Access to Anything that we listed for $10</span>
<p style="font-family:'Myriad Web Pro'; font-size:12pt">Please Insert Your Minecraft Username Below.</p>


  <INPUT TYPE="Text" VALUE="username" NAME="username" method="POST">

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p style="font-family:'Myriad Web Pro'; font-size:12pt">Item You Wish to Buy:</p>

<form name="myform" action="purchaseconfirm.php" method="POST">

  <div align="center">
  <select name="item">
<option value="10k Cash ingame ">$10,000.00 In Game Cash - iConomy</option>
<option value="Diamond Set(Armor and Wep/tools x2)">Full Set of All Diamond (Includes Armor and Tools/Wepons) x2</option>
<option value="item">item</option>
</select>




<p style="font-family:'Myriad Web Pro'; font-size:12pt">If you Abuse this and the paypal logs are checked. you will not recieve your item as you are breaking our Rules and as a consequense you will not recieve your item.</p>
<p style="font-family:'Myriad Web Pro'; font-size:12pt">Please Send us A Screenshot of your Payment Proof to Haxconnect24@gmail.com with your Computer Clock Being Shown, it is easy to tell a Fraud Image. Dont Try. </p>
<p style="font-family:'Myriad Web Pro'; font-size:12pt">After your Purchase you will be Banned from Tengokucraft Shop for:  1 week (168 Hours or 10,080 Minutes or 604,800 Seconds), This is a Security Measure</p>
<p style="font-family:'Myriad Web Pro'; font-size:12pt"><BR />
  <input type="submit" value="Pressing this Button You agree to the Terms Above and Schedrule the Item to be Given To you">
</p>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php


$directory_self = str_replace(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

$logfile= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $directory_self . 'purchases.html';


$logdetails=  date("F j, Y, g:i a") . ' : <br>Username:<br> ' . $_POST['username'] . ' <br>Item Purchased:<br> ' . $_POST['item'] . '</p>';



$fp = fopen($logfile, "a"); 
fwrite($fp, $logdetails);
fwrite($fp, " <br>----------------------<br>");
fclose($fp); 
echo "Your Purchase And your Item Request Was Recieved. it Will Now be Schedruled to Be given to you in the Post Office!, You have been Banned for 1 Week as a Security Measure. Thank you!";






?>
```

Outcome:

```
DATE(ignore this i removed it) : 
Username:

Item Purchased:
10k Cash ingame

----------------------
```

ive tried several things and i cant fix this.
is there anyway this can be fixed? i am using Dreamweaver CS5.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because

```
 <INPUT TYPE="Text" VALUE="username" NAME="username" method="POST">
```

is on outside of your `<form>`
You have to copy it under `<form name="myform" .....` . Also this `<input>` must be like this :

```
<INPUT TYPE="Text" VALUE="username" NAME="username">
```

You can use `method=''` parameter with `<form>` tag, only.

Comment: Thanks! could you help me with a PHP time Block Script?

Comment: sure, if you give me more details (mayba in new question)